# No Ubuntu 5.X kernel boots successfully

Tags: boot, nvidia, kernel

I have the problem that basically every Ubuntu Kernel since 5.3.0-46 which I tried out got stuck while booting so I assume there has to be a general issue but I just don't have any idea anymore to find out what breaking.

The last kernel which is working is 4.15.0-96 which I still use right now with Ubuntu 20.04 to which I upgraded yesterday because the new 5.4.0-29 as well does not work.

Shortly describing my HW, I use a ASUS ROG Notebook with an intel and nvidia graphics card, dualbooting windows and ubuntu so I do not really need the nvidia card on ubuntu and to be honest I never got it working since starting with Ubuntu 18.04.

What I did until right now:
- tried to manually install different kernels from the mainline ppa while deactivating secure-boot
- deactivated loading the graphic card driver using nomodeset

I am not an expert with using linux in general but I tried to follow a lot of answers here on the board but nothing worked.

Hope you can help me solving this issue.

Comment: what were your results from your attempts to narrow the issue down via the mainline PPA? You need to find as close as you can from there, and then bisect the kernel to isolate the exact commit that results in your issue. First try Kernel 5.7-rc5, to see if your issue has been fixed upstream. By the way, mainline kernels are not Ubuntu kernels, they are upstream kernels.

Comment: Issues occured first when upgrading from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 with Kernel 5.3.XX I think I tried afterwards a hand full of 5.1.X and 5.2.X always with the same result and I do not remember if I tried even older ones. I will now try out 5.7-rc5.

Comment: Okay 5.7-rc5 works. Is there any way that I at least could find out what exactly is not working fine, e.g. some log during the boot process, otherwise I have to dig through all the latest upstream kernels.

Comment: I only know of bisecting the kernel to isolate the exact issue. Bisection is a lot of work, and it is very easy to make a mistake and end up in the wrong spot. Since your issue is fixed upstream, it should eventually get picked up by various backports, it might just take awhile.

Comment: I tried out the latest 5.6.13 and there it works as well. I signed the kernel so that I can enable secure boot again otherwise Windows is making problems. Just because I am curious isn't there a way to identify some logs mentioning exactly what is broken when booting the previous not working kernels?

Comment: Yes, there would be logs somewhere, it can be hard to find the correct one. 3 times out of 4, I will find out lots about an issue after I have bisected the kernel, whereas I don't know exactly what to look for before the bisection. You can try the [changelog for 5.6.13](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.6.13/0004-debian-changelog.patch)